# Elastic load balancer rules:Direct all traffic coming from particular application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am trying to create a load balancer in AWS which directs all traffic coming from particular application to specific target group.

What rule should I implement if I need to forward all traffic signals coming from a single application to any specific target group?

Answer (score 0):

You can use query-string rule to detect requests sent by your specific application, for example: source=my-app-1

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#path-conditions

> Query string conditions You can use query string conditions to
> configure rules that route requests based on key/value pairs or values
> in the query string. The match evaluation is not case-sensitive. The
> following wildcard characters are supported: * (matches 0 or more
> characters) and ? (matches exactly 1 character).